# Plotting a graph with given double coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, graph, vector-graphics

I receive an array of coordinates (`double` coordinates with `-infinity < x < +infinity` and `0 <= y <= 10`) and want to draw a polyline using those points. I want the graph to always begin on the left border of my image, and end at the right. The bottom border of my image always represents a 0 `y`-value, and the top border always a  10 `y`-value. The width and height of the image that is created are decided by the user at runtime.

I want to realize this using Qt, and `QImage` in combination with `QPainter` seem to be my primary weapons of choice. The problem I am currently trying to solve is:

**How to convert my coordinates to pixels in my image?**

The `y`-values seem to be fairly simple, since I know the minimum and maximum of the graph beforehand, but I am struggling with the `x`-values. My approach so far is to find the min- and max-`x`-value and scale each point respectively.

**Is there a more native approach?**

Since one set of coordinates serves for several images with different widths and heights, I wondered whether a vector graphic (svg) may be a more suitable approach, but I couldn't find material on creating svg-files within Qt yet, just working with existing files. I would be looking for something comparable to the Windows  metafiles.

**Is there a close match to metafiles in Qt?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGraphicsScene` may help in this case. You plot the graph with either `addPolygon()` or `addPath()`. Then render the scene into a bitmap with [`QGraphicsScene::render()`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#render)

The `sceneRect` will automatically grow as you add items to it. At the end of the "plotting" you will get the final size/bounds of the graph. Create a `QImage` and use it as the painter back store to render the scene.

`QGraphicsScene` also allows you to manipulate the transformation matrix to fit the orientation and scale to your need.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to use **[QtOpenGL](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtopengl.html)** to render your 2d graph to a openGL context. No conversion/scaling of coordinates is required. Once you get past the opengl basics you can pick appropriate viewPort / eye parameters to achieve any zoom/pan level.

Comment: Not having to convert or scale is great, but isn't OpenGL very expensive on a "small" operation such as drawing a single polyline?

Comment: @nijansen I have profiled any QT app recently but openGl is usually hard accelerated so if anything it will be faster if not the same